# Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'c' for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-update, inner-join

I'm trying to prepare myself for feature interviews and while I was trying to solve this problem I have encountered some issues at the last exercise C).

[image]

I have recreated these tables on my local database "labsd" and this is my solution to

A)

```
SELECT  labsd.interns.email,labsd.grades.grade
from labsd.grades
Inner join labsd.interns on labsd.interns.id=labsd.grades.id
Order by labsd.grades.grade desc
Limit 10;
```

B)

```
SELECT count(labsd.grades.id),labsd.grades.grade
from grades
group by labsd.grades.grade
order by count(labsd.grades.id) desc;
```

And here is the problem

C)

```
Update labsd.interns as c
Set c.Accepted=1
where labsd.interns.id In (SELECT  labsd.interns.id
from labsd.grades
Inner join labsd.interns on labsd.interns.id=labsd.grades.id
Order by labsd.grades.grade desc);
```

Considering that at the first point I was asked for the top 10 students I thought I should reuse that code but I can not use Limit anymore and I got the following error :

```
Error Code: 1235. This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

I don't know how to find what version of MySql do I have just installed it this semester so I assume it is the last version.

And even without using the limit I still get the error mentioned in the title. I have tried to rename the table but it hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: MySQL and SQL-Server both are different kindly remove one you are not using.

Comment: "so I assume it is the last version." - why? There is zero logic in that. The error message (which I assume comes form the C# side) indiates that there IS a versoin that supports LIMIT, and there is zero indication this has been removed, so the logical conclusion is that (a) new vesions support it and (b) YOUR vesion does not support it, so in conclusion you CAN NOT run a current version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL does not allow the syntax that you are trying to use. Instead, you can use the update/join syntax as follows:

```
update labsd.interns s
inner join (
    select i.id
    from labsd.grades g
    inner join labsd.interns i on i.id = g.id
    order by g.grade desc limit 10
) t on t.id = s.id
set s.accepted = 1
```

The subquery enumerates the `id`s of the 10 best candidates, then the outer query joins the results of the subquery with the original table, an sets the flags on matching rows.

Comment: So t is another table created dynamically from the query from Question A? I' m just a beginner and I  haven't seen this type of syntax so far.

Comment: @CristianFlaviu: yes, that's called a *derived table*.

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign an alias in the Update portion.

Remove the alias entirely,

`Update labsd.interns
Set Accepted=1`

or rewrite the query to move `as c` into the join statement.

`UPDATE       c
SET          Accepted = 1
FROM         labsd.grades as g
JOIN labsd.interns AS c 
ON c.id = g.id;`

Note you also can't have an `Order By` in a subquery without a top clause.

Comment: The reason why I have added the alias is because I got this error and  I have read that using an alias might help.   I have rewrite the code like this but I got the same error                                                                                        
  Update labsd.interns 
Set labsd.interns.Accepted=1
where labsd.interns.id In (SELECT labsd.interns.id
from labsd.grades
Inner join labsd.interns as c    on  c.id=labsd.grades.id
Order by labsd.grades.grade desc);